# JavaScript onload and onerror not being called

Tags: javascript

```
var images;
function preloadTrial(actor, event) {
  return new Promise(function(res) {
    var i = 0;
    images = [];
    var handler = function(resolve, reject) {
      var img = new Image;
      var source = '/static/videos/' + actor + '/' + event + '/' + i + '.png';
      img.onload = function() {
        i++;
        resolve(img);
      }
      img.onerror = function() {
        reject()
      }
      img.src = source;
    }
    var _catch = function() { res(images) }
    var operate = function(value) {
      if (value) images.push(value);
      new Promise(handler).then(operate).catch(_catch);
    }
    operate();
  })
}

function playSequence(time){
  var delta = (time - currentTime) / 1000;
  currentFrame += (delta * FPS);
  var frameNum = Math.floor(currentFrame);
  if (frameNum >= numFramesPlay) {
    currentFrame = frameNum = 0;
    return;
  }else{
    requestAnimationFrame(playSequence);
    currentImage.src = images[frameNum];
    currentTime = time;
    console.log("display"+currentImage.src);
  }
};

function rightNow() {
  if (window['performance'] && window['performance']['now']) {
    return window['performance']['now']();
  } else {
    return +(new Date());
  }
};

currentImage = document.getElementById("instructionImage");
// Then use like this
preloadTrial('examples', 'ex1').then(function(value) {
  playSequence(currentTime=rightNow());
});
```

I wrote a Javascript function that is suppose to load a directory full of numbered .png files. However, I do not know the number of items inside the directory beforehand. So I made a function that continues to store images until the source gives me an error. But when I run the code the program does not even enter the .onload and .onerror functions, resulting in an infinite loop.

Edit: This is my current code. It appears that images are correctly assigned and pushed into the array images. But when I attempt to load it onto a img tag (currentImage.src) and run playSequence, it does not display.

Comment: I think `/static` is trying to find the folder `static` in the root (`/`) directory. What's the file structure set up like? Does changing it to `./static` or `static` do anything?

Comment: @J. Chen no that's not the problem. It works with a for loop. The only reason I'm using a while is because I don't know the number of images.

Comment: Get rid of `on`.  It's for HTML not script.

Comment: I think what's happening is that images[i] is constantly being written. I'm assuming the while loop runs faster than the image object loads; when you do `images[i].src = source;`, it tries to load the source, but the while-loop iterates faster and we hit the line `images[i] = new Image();` before our source can be loaded.

Comment: @J. Chen, how would I fix that?

Comment: You should use a promise to resolve onload and reject onerror, then load the next one until you catch the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use promises to handle the pre-loading of the images. 
Chain the resolves on the onload event and reject onerror to end the cycle.

```
function preloadImages(baseurl, extension, starter) {
  return new Promise(function(res) {
    var i = starter;
    var images = [];
    // Inner promise handler
    var handler = function(resolve, reject) {
      var img = new Image;
      var source = baseurl + i + '.' + extension;
      img.onload = function() {
        i++;
        resolve(img);
      }
      img.onerror = function() {
        reject('Rejected after '+ i + 'frames.');
      }
      img.src = source;
    }
    // Once you catch the inner promise you resolve the outer one.
    var _catch = function() { res(images) }
    var operate = function(value) {
      if (value) images.push(value);
      // Inner recursive promises chain.
      // Stop with the catch resolving the outer promise.
      new Promise(handler).then(operate).catch(_catch);
    }
    operate();
  })
}
```

To simulate a video player, you can draw on a HTML5 canvas.

```
function play(canvas, imagelist, refreshRate, frameWidth, frameHeight) {
    // Since we're using promises, let's promisify the animation too.
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        // May need to adjust the framerate
        // requestAnimationFrame is about 60/120 fps depending on the browser
        // and the refresh rate of the display devices.
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var ts, i = 0, delay = 1000 / refreshRate;
        var roll = function(timestamp) {
            if (!ts || timestamp - ts >= delay) {
                // Since the image was prefetched you need to specify the rect.
                ctx.drawImage(imagelist[i], 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
                i++;
                ts = timestamp;
            }
            if (i < imagelist.length) 
                requestAnimationFrame(roll);
            else 
                resolve(i);
        }
        roll();
    })
}
```

To test I used ffmpeg to cut a video with the following command:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:14.435 -vframes 100 %d.png`

And I used devd.io to quickly create a static folder containing the script and images and a basic index.html.

[imageroller.js](https://gist.github.com/T4rk1n/e2fa86798e073ecde102666c42ebc146) - with the above code.

```
var preload = preloadImages('/static/videos/examples/testvid/', 'png', 1);
preload.then(function(value) {
    console.log('starting play');
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    play(canvas, value, 24, 720, 400) // ~480p 24fps
        .then(function(frame){ 
            console.log('roll finished after ' + frame + ' frames.') 
        })
});
```

While the preloading of the images was pretty slow, if you keep the number of frames to an acceptable level you can make some nice loops.

Comment: what is wrong with my old way of animation and is there no way of remedying it? Thank you so much for the answer btw.

Comment: @AlexKer I did not see `currentFrame` defined before use so when you did `currentFrame += (delta * FPS)` you got NaN and you never got your frame.

Comment: I did define it before. I can update my code. But your code works very well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the snippet below (and there are probably cleaner solutions) but the idea should be correct. Basically we have a recursive function `loadImages()`, and we pass in the `images` array and a callback function. We wait for our current image to load; if it loads, we push it into `images` and call `loadImages()` again. If it throws an error, we know we are finished loading, so we return our callback function. Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
function preloadTrial(actor, event) {
  let images = [];
  loadImages(images, actor, event, function () {
    // code to run when done loading
  });
};

function loadImages (images, actor, event, callback) {
  let img = new Image();
  let i = images.length;
  let source ='/static/videos/'+actor+'/'+event+'/'+i+'.png';
  img.onload = function() {
    images.push(img);
    return loadImages(images, actor, event, callback);
  }
  img.onerror = function() {
    return callback(images);
  }
  img.src = source;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The optimal solution would be to provide a server-side API that tells you beforehand, how many Images there are in the directories.
If that is not possible, you should load the images one after the other to prevent excess requests to the server. In this case i would put the image loading code in a separate function and call it if the previous image was loaded successfully, like so:

```
function loadImage(actor, event, i, loadCallback, errorCallback) {
var image = new Image();
var source ='/static/videos/'+actor+'/'+event+'/'+i+'.png';
image.onload = loadCallback;
image.onerror = errorCallback;
image.src = source;
return image;
}
```

and then call this function in your while loop and in the loadCallback.